# Linq: Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'

Tags: linq

I want to divide one value with another. The formula goes like this

If (Job2 =0, 0, Job2/Job1)
The code i wrote is:

```
 double empJob1Count = empYearMonthGroup
     .Where(x => x.Row["Job2"] != DBNull.Value)
     .Sum(x => x.Row.Field<double>("Job2")/ x => x.Row.Field<double>("Job1"));
```

But getting error, Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'. please suggest how can this be done with linq c#?

Comment: A division of two lambda expressions is certainly interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You already have `x` parameter in result selector. Here is correct syntax:

```
double empJob1Count = empYearMonthGroup
     .Where(x => x.Row["Job2"] != DBNull.Value)
     .Sum(x => x.Row.Field<double>("Job2") / x.Row.Field<double>("Job1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Field` extension method which supports nullable types:

```
double empJob1Count = empYearMonthGroup
    .Where(x => x.Row.Field<double?>("Job2").HasValue)
    .Sum(x => x.Row.Field<double?>("Job2").Value / x.Row.Field<double>("Job1"));
```

However, the problem in your code is the second `x =>`.

Comment: I am getting "NaN" for columns where there is no values i.e. where Job2 is blank or it have 0.0 as value. How can I resolve this?